# Array object function and trasform

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

i need to trasform this

```
const persons = [
  {id:7 ,firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
  {id:7, firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Frye"},
  {id:2,firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];
```

in

```
const persons_ = [
  {id:7 ,
   firstname : "Malcom",
   item: [{lastname: "Reynolds"},{lastname: "Frye"}]
  } ,
  {id:2,
  firstname : "Jayne", 
  item:[{lastname: "Cobb"}]
  }
];
```

(grouping by id)
can you help me? tks

peraphs i resolve with this code:

```
     const copyItems = []
persons.forEach(function(item_){
  const found = copyItems.find(element => element.id == item_.id);
  if (!(found)){
    copyItems.push( {id:item_.id,firstname:item_.firstname,item:[{lastname: item_.lastname}]}    )
   }else
   {
    var item ={lastname: item_.lastname}
    copyItems[copyItems.length-1].item.push(item)
   }
})
```

but i suppose there is a better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I group an array of objects by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key) It may not be an exact fit, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Please add whatever you have tried. Your approach and effort will lead to better response